# XSL - match text of node and append another node as sibling

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have XML like this:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>some text here</c>
  </b>
</a>
<a>
  <b>
    <c>another cool text</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

I need to match word "cool" inside //a/b/c/text() and transform the XML like this

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>some text here</c>
  </b>
</a>
<x>
  <y> prepend to cool text </y>
</x>
<a>
  <b>
    <c>another cool text</c>
  </b>
</a>
```

I tried this:

```
<xsl:template
        match="//a/b/c/matches(text(),'\.*cool\*.')">
...
</xsl:template>
```

but with no luck:

```
XTSE0340: XSLT Pattern syntax error at char 153 on line 30 in {...\.*cool\*...}:
  Function call may appear only at the start of a pattern
```

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your match is not correct, it should test inside brackets `[]`:

```
<xsl:template
        match="//a/b/c[matches(text(), '.*cool.*')]">
...
</xsl:template>
```

Besides, if your regexp is that easy, then you can use the XPath method `contains()`.

Comment: Thanks, that what I was looking for, in my case it is not that simple so I really need regexp. Anyway, thanks for quick answer!